# Which direction does code in the memory get executed?

Tags: c, stack, shellcode

Suppose I have shellcode injected into the memory of a process, which way will the shellcode get executed? Assuming higher memory addresses are on bottom of stack and lower memory addresses are on top of stack, does the shellcode run from lowest memory address of shellcode to highest memory address of shellcode or the other way round?

Comment: the program counter (aka instruction pointer) typically moves from lower to higher memory addresses (except for branches of course).

Comment: That was a mistake. Btw Sander, can you alter the direction of eip movement changing the DF flag?

Comment: the DF flag is relevant when copying data only, not when moving the program counter forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program counter (aka instruction pointer) typically moves from lower to higher memory addresses (except for branches and function calls/returns of course).

Answer (score 3):

Branches aside, for CPUs from the x86 family, the IP can only go from a lower to a higher number.

Before execution, the IP sits at the beginning of an instruction. The CPU does not know how long an instruction is until it has been decoded. It would not be possible to go in the other direction because it would be impossible to determine if the last byte of the prior instruction was an argument or part of the instruction coding itself.

The stack grows from higher to lower addresses. (This probably has historical origins from when the stack and heap memory shared the same area of RAM.) However, this does not mean that data stored on the stack is in reverse order - it's just that newly allocated stack space has a lower address than what was allocated prior.

Comment: IP isn't really directly exposed, but RIP-relative addressing is relative to the *end* of the instruction.  It would make the most sense to say that IP = end of this instruction, start of next instruction, during execution of an instruction.  In fact, original 8086 didn't have any exceptions that pushed the instruction start address, so the CPU probably didn't even save that.  (`#DE` faults were taking with fault address = end of the `div` or `idiv` instruction.  See this answer on [x86 Program Counter abstracted from microarchitecture?](//stackoverflow.com/a/57172505))

Answer (score 0):

You care about the direction of which the stack pointer is going to move. Stack pointer points to the end of that memory block (your process lives in) at the beginning and decremented whenever a new value is pushed (and incremented whenever popped).

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to understand which direction will my shellcode get executed. Could you kindly elaborate/explain your answer :)